# No KeyChar property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Guys there is no KeyChar property to get a character from textBox in WPF C# project. Is there any alternative to get character on pressing any key??

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.keyChar == (char)13)
            {
                webBrowser.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Return)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will surely work in WPF

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtbx" KeyDown="OnKeyDown" Height="23" Width="250">
</TextBox>

private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Home(or whatever key you want, if it is numeri try with D0, D1,D2 etc.))
    {
        txtbx.Text = "You Entered: " + txtbx.Text;
    }
}
```